# Osmdroid positionate MarkerInfoWindow

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I implement custom `MarkerInfoWindow` and when i click to my POI on map, map moves to center of the screen and half of my `MarkerInfoWindow` is cut by toolbar.

How i can move map at the bottom of the screen, when i tapped on POI to show all `MarkerInfoWindow`

How it looks like now:

[image: How it looks like now]

How it should be:

[image: How it should be]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your own Marker.OnMarkerClickListener class, with its onMarkerClic method.

And then call: 
myMarker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MyOnMarkerClickListener listener);

Have a look at Marker.onMarkerClickDefault to see an example. 
You will have some maths to do to move the map at the desired position.